# Does Brain Toniq soft drink improve cognition?

Tags: medications, concentration

*Brain Toniq* is a non-caffeinated soft drink that contains:

> Rhodiola root, Choline, DMAE, and organic wild-harvested Blue Green Algae extract

While their [web-site](http://www.braintoniq.com/) and their [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/TrueToniq) make no claims about the pharacological effects of the drink, some of the retailers, such as this [Amazon page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00128DPT2) claim it helps improve brain function:

> Brain Toniq is the world's first botanical-based, non-caffeinated think drink specifically designed for those who need more mental focus and clarity. Formulated out of plant extracts, natural compounds, and organic agave nectar, the ingredients in Brain Toniq are known for their effects on increasing brain power and cognition. We add no chemical preservatives, no caffeine, no processed sugar, no fake anything. Just fuel for the cranium. ••• Most people will tell you that there is a lull in cognitive power during some part of their day. They intuitively know that adding more caffeine isn't the answer; in fact that's probably a recipe for digestive and skin problems, as well as adrenal burnout. Instead, they are looking for a healthy way to get their brain circulation and mental capacities back on line. ••• Brain Toniq is the antidote to head fog. It was made by and for people who understand the role that health plays in accomplishing ones life vision. If you have a need for getting things done, Brain Toniq can help you get there. You get a formula made from effective doses of Rhodiola root, Choline and DMAE (two natural compounds extracted from legumes), Eleuthero root ("Siberian Ginseng") and organic wild-harvested Blue Green Algae extract. We add a mix of natural citrus extracts, use only 100% organic agave nectar for sweetness, and add a light carbonation for a 100% vegan beverage. It's a delicious flavor, one that even kids enjoy. No caffeine. No processed sugars. No fake anything. Just fuel for intelligent decision making. ••• You make a living from your brain. Start feeding it the fuel it needs.

I've used the stuff in the past, and did seem to have a serious effect, but of course that might have been a mere placebo. And, given how expensive the stuff is, I'd rather take a sugar pill for that.

Do these chemicals help improve cognition?

Comment: Product disclaimer states, 'content on this site is for reference purposes and is not intended to substitute for advice given by a physician, pharmacist, or other licensed health-care professional. You should not use this information as self-diagnosis or for treating a health problem or disease. Contact your health-care provider immediately if you suspect that you have a medical problem. Information and statements regarding dietary supplements have not been evaluated by the Food and Drug Administration and are not intended to diagnose, treat, cure, or prevent any disease or health condition.'

Comment: Recommended reading article #1-http://www.csicop.org/si/show/science_and_pseudoscience_in_adult_nutrition_research_and_practice/ and article #2-http://www.csicop.org/specialarticles/show/methodological_and_statistical_issues_in_adult_nutritional_research for skeptical and scientific analysis of supplement ingredients in nutritional research.

Comment: Supplement Geek on Cholne is here: http://supplement-geek.com/nootrobrain-review/